# Executing many native queries in @Query() of CrudRepository or JpaRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, crud

how to execute many native queries with @Query() of CrudRepository or JpaRepository:
example:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from A_B_LIST where B_LIST_ID = ?1; delete from B where ID = ?1;", nativeQuery=true)
deleteById(@Param("id") Long id);

here the schema of bd: 
 table A: |id|  table B: |id|  table A_B_LIST: |A_LIST_ID|B_LIST_ID|  foreigns keys:
          | 1|           | 1|                  |    1    |    1    |  A_B_LIST.A_LIST_ID -> A.ID
                         | 2|                  |    1    |    2    |  A_B_LIST.B_LIST_ID -> B.ID
```

Comment: I think you should replace 1? with :id and use @Param("id") instead of @PathParam("id").

Comment: Sorry, I am using native query. ps: I update my question.

Comment: It's not a problem at all, in spring-data documentation you can check section **2.3.5 Using named parameters**, spring docs says that @Param annotation solve the problem of position based query to give a method parameter a concrete name and bind the name in the query

Comment: My problem it's how  to excute 2 sql queries under @Query. ps: my example generate this error:  `JpaRepository @query JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal `

Comment: Which version of JPA you are using ? Note that in JPA >= 2.0 you can use named parameters in a native query.

Comment: I thik the problem is not related to binding parameters but to know if it is possible to concatenate 2 sql queries ?

Comment: no it's not about the query, it's about the repeated **?1**